# How to send enum value to API using Angular 5?

Tags: angular, enums

Hi I am working on web application developed on Angular 5. I am sending data back to API. API model is as below.

```
public partial class ResourceDTO
       {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("state")]
        public State State { get; set; }
       }
public enum State 
{
      NotSelected = 0,
      Allowed = 1,
      Denied = 2
}
```

I want to send data to the API. Below is my enum defined in type script.

```
export enum State {
    NotSelected,
    Allowed,
    Denied 
}
```

In below function I am consolidating my data.

```
 data.forEach(element => {
            const object = { modelType: '', userroleid: '', name: [], hasChildren: false, id: '', state: State };
           
            if (element.id != undefined) {
                object.id = element.id;
            }
            if (element.checked == false) {
                object.state.NotSelected;
            }
            if (element.checked == true) {
                object.state.Allowed;
            }
            if (element.allow == false) {
                object.state.Denied;
            }
            saveData.push(object);
        });
```

Below is the saveData after consolidating the data.

[image]

Can someone tell me Am I doing it correctly or something I am missing? Above output is expected one? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your last 3 if statements don't do anything, what do you think they should do?

Comment: As per my knowledge if element.checked is false then state.NotSelected should set. If element.checked is true then state.Allowed should set. Let me know if i am doing wrong?

Comment: right, so you need to do the assignment: `object.state = State.Allowed;` etc.

Comment: I have added   object.state = State.NotSelected; now I am getting error type state.notselected is not assignable to type 'type of state'

Comment: I would also suggest instead of sending the whole state enum , just send the selected state as string

Comment: Yeah but i cant change back end model.

Comment: @Niranjan You initialized `object.state` to the `State` object. I doubt you wanted to do that... Were you trying to declare its type instead?

Comment: @Niranjan how you understand from the server which value is selected from the client by looking at the all whole enum , typescript by default assign 0,1,2 to the enum values when declaration itself

Comment: Yes it assigns 0,1,2 and so on. so how to send now?

Comment: @Niranjan  I think your expectation is selected value should be 1 or true and rested of the values should be 0 or 'false' in the server..I am right??

Comment: yeah so how to set it now

Comment: @Niranjan You can't set a value to typescript enum because  it's readonly . Alternative is create an object literal same as enum and assign the value to each property based on the condition

Comment: Actually only one state at a time send back. Is there any way we can do this? for example, Notselected,Allowed or Denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a typescript enum value , because it's readonly . You can try the below alternative by creating an object literal and set the value based on the selection before you post to the server

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html

```
 const object = { modelType: '', userroleid: '', name: [], hasChildren: false, id: '', state: {}};

var newState ={
"Allowed": element.checked,
"NotSelected":!element.checked,
"Denied":element.allow == false
}

object.state=newState;
 if (element.id != undefined) {
                object.id = element.id;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this